# Dynamic properties of object in c# webform

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a n properties of ShowSeat Class: SeatCol1Status , SeatCol2Status ..., SeatColnStatus
I want list value of this to view, but I don't like

```
<%= ShowSeats[rowIndex].SeatCol1Status %>
<%= ShowSeats[rowIndex].SeatCol2Status %>
..................
<%= ShowSeats[rowIndex].SeatColnStatus %>
```

How do generate it with loop in html of webform

Answer (score 0):

You can add an indexed property that you can then loop over (guessing at the return type):

```
public SeatStatus SeatStatus[int col]
{
  get
   {
      switch(col)
        case 1: return SeatCol1Status;
        case 2: return SeatCol2Status;
        // etc    
   }
}
```

But maybe you shouldn't have made "n" specific properties but just a single one, containing a list of "seat statusses" that you can index into (and easily iterate over). And this also adapts easily when not all rows have the same number of seats.